# Plymouth Bootloader not intercepting keyboard input?

Tags: boot, nvidia, plymouth

I recently installed the NVIDIA drivers for my computer's GTX 1080. After doing this, the Plymouth boot animation I am using fails to intercept passwords correctly.

[image: Credential Error]

Instead of Plymouth getting the password, it just gets written to the side of the screen as seen in the above image. Pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> does not cause any events to run. Effectively, my system is soft-locked and requires a hard restart. I am not even able to switch to a TTY or similar.

It also appears as though this is overwriting the actual screen - a blinking underscore appears in the corner, and any characters write over Plymouth. This seems to suggest Plymouth has failed somehow, and is instead dropping back to a (broken) shell. This appears to be very similar to [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=210299) over on the Arch Linux Forums. I have not yet tried updating to the latest compiled version of Plymouth, and would like to avoid it if possible. This also appears to be covered in Bug [#1386005](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005) for Plymouth.

This issue does not happen with the Nouveau drivers, and booting without splash does not cause this issue.

My `/etc/default/grub` has the following lines in it:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=3840x2160
```

I also have a `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` file, with the following content:

```
Framebuffer=y
```

Setting Framebuffer to `n` will also do nothing.

I am running NVIDIA driver version 387.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 (with HWE kernel). The bootloader theme is custom, but based off of the Ubuntu default.

Running with `nosplash` as an option works normally, and I can enter my password as expected (although I do miss my boot screen). Retrieving Plymouth logs is impossible as my hard drive is encrypted, and I can not decrypt it when Plymouth is active.

How can I fix my Plymouth bootloader while I wait for an official bugfix?

Comment: I have had several issues with Plymouth and nvidia proprietary drivers. The most common issue has been that Plymouth is simply skipped, and it is OK for me with a text screen during boot. So I suggest that you boot without splash (that is what I would do).

Comment: @sudodus That is what I am currently using, because I need my system to work. However, I'd rather not let a nice boot screen go to waste. :)

Comment: You have a nice boot screen, and I can understand that you want to use it, but I am happy enough when the proprietary driver works with Ubuntu when logged in and running application programs with advanced graphics ;-)